# Docker COPY cmd that respects .dockerignore?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerignore

I have a folder `tmpdata` with slightly different permissions at the top level of my project, which is used by a separate container to be able to restart with data.

I list this `tmpdata/` folder in my `.dockerignore` file because I don't want it to be part of the build for the main app.

In my Dockerfile, I do have a `COPY . .` directive though. I thought it would copy everything except whatever's listed in .dockerignore, but when I try to build, I get:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open tmpdata: permission denied
```

My question is, why isn't the `.dockerignore` file preventing the build process from even trying to touch this folder? Is there a way to have the COPY command respect (ignore) entries in the `.dockerignore` file?

**UPDATE** even after refactoring the dockerfile to use selective `COPY` commands that only copy needed files, docker build still fails, complaining about the same `tmpdata` folder.

**UPDATE 2** my docker ignore file:

```
.dockerignore
docker-compose.yml
.env
.env.*
.git
test/
src/test/
**/*.spec.*
**/*.test.*
**/node_modules/
npm-debug.log
.gitignore
.cache
.DS_Store
.thumbsdb 
dist/
_unused/
.vscode/
**/*.md
**/.git
tmpdata/
```

Comment: I have just tried this and got the same results as you. You can get around it by changing the permissions on the tmpdata folder to enable docker to access it. It will not be copied even though it is accessible. I have no idea why docker is doing this but it looks wrong to me.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Good idea. I did `chmod g+r` on the folder and that seems to have let docker build in peace. I agree with you though that it's strange behavior! I have still to poke around in the resulting container to confirm what `COPY . .` _actually_ did, just out of curiosity...

Comment: so although the build succeeded once the folder was make readable, the `COPY .  .` STILL copied EVERYTHING over, in spite of .dockerignore. Wow. So what is the point of dockerignore then...

Comment: I tried it and although it needed access to the folder it didn't copy it. What's in your .dockerignore file?

Comment: Added dockerignore contents to my Q!
OK so since I'm running ls on the running container, it will have regenerated node_modules anyway since it has to install modules. I can't recall whether i saw tmpdata specifically; I don't think I did. I did see pretty much all the files in my project dir though. Looking at other SO answers, it looks like this is the bhvior. The ignore list is only used for "build context" whatever that is, and COPY literally copies whatever u tell it. I'm not really understanding the difference, tbh. But I've moved to no special folders, and explicit COPYs.

Comment: The "build context" is a copy of the folder (and subfolders) from the location you ran `docker build`. It's sometimes the case that the CLI is referencing a remote docker server so the context is sent to the server (which in your case, happens to be local) for processing by the instructions in the dockerfile. The `.dockerignore` file is supposed to exclude things from the context so that you can control the amount of data sent over the wire and perhaps stop sensitive data being sent too.

Comment: And your `.dockerignore` file looks a little over-engineered but basically ok. The best solution is, as you say, to not have special folders and explicitly copying is a better approach anyway because it documents your intent better.